# How to add a rule to CheckStyle.xml

Tags: java, intellij-idea, checkstyle

How to add a rule to CheckStyle.xml (IDEA) which will mark as an error the use of certain characters, for example: [ ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [IllegalTokenText rule](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html#IllegalTokenText).
Include the following inside the  tag to mark the violation of this rule as error:

```
<property name="severity" value="error"/>
```

Full example:

```
<module name = "Checker">
    <property name="charset" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="severity" value="warning"/>
    ...
    <module name="TreeWalker">
        ...
        <module name="IllegalTokenText">
            <property name="severity" value="error"/>
            <property name="tokens" value="STRING_LITERAL"/>
            <property name="format" value="abc|xyz"/>
            <property name="ignoreCase" value="true"/>
        </module>
        ...
    </module>
</module>
```

Which generates the following error:

```
Token text matches the illegal pattern 'abc'. [IllegalTokenText]
```

Comment: Thanks, almost what you need, this method takes only one character, but how to specify a few characters for verification?

Comment: The value for the format property is a regular expression, so you would need to use the pipe character `|` to match multiple (stand alone) values. Please consult java regex documentation for more details. I have updated the code example for you.